Protobuf-generated Python class does not have accessible functions or fields
I need to read a protobuf message in Python. I’ve defined the message in a file order.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

message Order {
 string orderId = 1;
 string userId = 2;
 repeated string products = 3;
 string createdAt = 4;
}

I generated the corresponding Python class order_pb2.py.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: order.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='order.proto',
  package='',
  syntax='proto3',
  serialized_options=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  serialized_pb=b'\n\x0border.proto\"M\n\x05Order\x12\x0f\n\x07orderId\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x0e\n\x06userId\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\x10\n\x08products\x18\x03 \x03(\t\x12\x11\n\tcreatedAt\x18\x04 \x01(\tb\x06proto3'
)




_ORDER = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Order',
  full_name='Order',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='orderId', full_name='Order.orderId', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=b"".decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='userId', full_name='Order.userId', index=1,
      number=2, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=b"".decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='products', full_name='Order.products', index=2,
      number=3, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='createdAt', full_name='Order.createdAt', index=3,
      number=4, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=b"".decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR,  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  serialized_options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto3',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=15,
  serialized_end=92,
)

DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Order'] = _ORDER
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)

Order = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Order', (_message.Message,), {
  'DESCRIPTOR' : _ORDER,
  '__module__' : 'order_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:Order)
  })
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Order)


# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)


I import it using the following:"
from order_pb2 import Order

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def onNewOrder():
 order = Order()
 

Even though the type of order is Order, I'm unable to access functions like ParseFromString or fields such as orderId. My IDE indicates that the attributes ParseFromString and orderId are unknown.
Additionally, there’s a bit of an issue: in order_pb2.py, the line at the very bottom, _sym_db.RegisterMessage(Order), shows an error. It indicates that the argument Order of type type[Order] cannot be assigned to the parameter message of type type[Message].
Installed: 
protoc --version: libprotoc 25.1 
pip protobuf: 5.28.0 
Python: 3.12.5
IDE: Visual Studio Code
I work in a python virtual env project. The Interpreter is set to python 3.12.5 ('env': venv')
what am I doing wrong? I hope for help.

Did you set --pyi_out= when you generated the files?

I cannot reproduce this behavior with Python 3.12 and protoc v28.

I used protoc --python_out=. order.proto using in Linux

I tried in VSCode with the below versions
PS C:\Users\X\Desktop\New folder> protoc --version
libprotoc 28.0
PS C:\Users\X\Desktop\New folder> 
PS C:\Users\X\Desktop\New folder> pip show protobuf
Name: protobuf
Version: 5.28.0

And below code, it seems to be working
from test_pb2 import Order

order = Order()
order.orderId = '1'
print(order.orderId) # this will show '1'
print(order.products) # this will show empty list


Even though the type of order is Order, I'm unable to access functions like ParseFromString or fields such as orderId. My IDE indicates that the attributes ParseFromString and orderId are unknown.

I am assuming you are saying that when you try to access fields using the dot operator, It doesn't autocomplete or something, you can try and use print(hasattr(order, 'orderId')) to check if your order has that attribute or not.
